# Can I move an element from one block to another with flexbox?

Tags: html, css

Now the site uses a script to move to another block. Can I move an element from one block to another with flexbox?

https://jsfiddle.net/Lxmo4stc/

```
<div class="soc">
  <a href="#" class="social-icon">facebook</a> <br>
  <a href="#" class="social-icon">twitter</a>
</div>

<div class="info">
  lorem 123
</div>

if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
   $('.social-icon').appendTo('.info');
}
```

When loaded from mobile elements - in one block, when from desktop - in another. I did not write resize function for this example.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with another block, is it another block level element with display:flex?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot move items in different blocks. 
The flexbox `order` property works only with children of the same flex container, such as:

```
<div class="soc">
  <a href="#" class="social-icon fb">facebook</a>
  <a href="#" class="social-icon tw">twitter</a>  
  <a href="#" class="social-icon ig">instagram</a>
</div>
```

In which you can assign orders to the fb, tw and ig class to change their appearance in the DOM.

In addition, you can assign the `flex-flow` property to the flex container (the `soc` class in your case) to a column / row -reverse to reverse all the children inside the container.

A full snippet with example is below:

```css
.soc {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

a {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.fb {
  order: 2;
}

.tw {
  order: 3;
}

.ig {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="soc">
  <a href="#" class="social-icon fb">facebook 2nd</a>
  <a href="#" class="social-icon tw">twitter 3rd</a>  
  <a href="#" class="social-icon ig">instagram 1st</a>
</div>
```

[MDN reference on `order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understood.